# Show X values on the top of columns in mschart

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, mschart

Is it possible to show values from axisX as a value on the column?
I'd like to make the same effect like with

`chart1.Series.First().IsValueShownAsLabel = true;`

but I don't want to show Y values but X values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
chart1.Series.First().Label = "#VALX";
```

**EDIT:** To hide empty values:

```
foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
    foreach (DataPoint p in series.Points)
        if (Math.Abs(p.YValues[0]) < 0.00000001)
            p.Label = String.Empty;
```

Comment: Exactly! And how to disable these numbers where Y = 0?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only hide them manually. I've updated my answer.

Comment: We can also compare just to 0, not to 0.00000001, but solution is good. Thanx